# Rxjs Promise like Observable

Tags: promise, rxjs

I'd like to find a receipt for provide a `Promise`like `Observable`
i mean:
that `Observable` provides a single value and completes,
and any subscriber (before and after completion) should get that single value.
i came out with a combination of `Rx.Observable.create` `publishLast` and `connect`.

```
var getPromiseLike=function(){
  console.log('getPromiseLike()');
  //// var an_object={}; <--- this should happen inside Obs function
  var prom_like = Rx.Observable.create(function(obs) {
    var an_object={};   /// <--- here !
    setTimeout(function(){
      obs.onNext(an_object);
      obs.onCompleted();
    },500);
  }).publishLast();
  prom_like.connect();
  return prom_like;
};

var promiselike=getPromiseLike();

var obj1;
promiselike
  .subscribe(function(obj){
    console.log('onNext1');
    obj1 = obj;
  },
  function(err){},
  function(){
    console.log('onComplete1');
  });


setTimeout(function(){
  promiselike
    .subscribe(function(obj){
      console.log('onNext2 obj1===obj :'+(obj1===obj)); //true
    },
    function(err){},
    function(){
      console.log('onComplete2');
    });
},1000);

/*LOGS:
getPromiseLike()
script.js:19 onNext1
script.js:24 onComplete1
script.js:31 onNext2 obj1===obj :true
script.js:35 onComplete2
*/
```

is this the simplest solution or there's some builtin that i missed?
[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fyqM2A?p=preview)

Comment: If you want get only once you can use ```take(1)``` http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/take.html or ```takeLast(1)``` http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/takelast.html

Comment: You're right, concerning how i wrote the code, but i made a mistake on it.. if the `an_object` is created inside the `Observable` function that wouldn't work.. (edited code)..   Anyway, I'm probably heading to the wrong direction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In RxJS typically a promise like construct is modeled with [`AsyncSubject`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/asyncsubject.md).

It has many of the properties that promises have and is useful:

- It only receives one value like a promise and will call next only with that value.
- It caches that value for all future computations.
- It's a Subject, so it's like a deferred in some promise libraries.

---

Note: Personally I see no issue with mixing promises with observables, I do it in my own code and Rx plays with promises nicely.

Comment: That's it! i found it out yesterday,.. its use is very straigthful, just, must take care of calling `onCompleted` as the subscribers will receive exclusively the last value before complete. and a difference between `Promise`s  is that `AsyncSubject` is not *protected*, meaning that consumers has access to its `onXxx` methods..  -Yes i know `Rxjs` generally handles promises transparently but i was trying to avoid adding a lib when i understand that `Rx` *embraces* that paradigm itself

Comment: Could `AsyncSubject` not being _protected_ be a purposeful mechanism to allow for cancellation?

Comment: Looking at code at https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Linq/QueryLanguage.Awaiter.cs, it appears that this could be the case. I can't seem to find the `Cancel(..)` method via google though. Perhaps I'll download the source and do a find declaration later.

Comment: @Benjamin-Gruenbaum What do you think of the approach of using any of the Observable.from*() functions or .toAsync() to create an Observable and then calling .take(1) to filter down to a single element in the sequence?  Something about having to call onCompleted() on the AsyncSubject in order to simulate the behavior of a Promise is a bummer to me.

Comment: @DWoldrich so just use promises with `fromPromise` or directly inside combinators.

Comment: @Benjamin-Gruenbaum hehe, oh yeah.  Promises are the best choice for one-shot async events.  I guess I was just trying to build a grand unified async programming theory out of RxJS, but that's silly.